# Date Convert in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters, visualforce

I am using a javascript in Visualforce page. I pass the value of Date (format is: 2016-06-14).

Now I want to convert this date into the following format: `June 14, 2016`.

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use very usefull library - [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().format('MMMM Do, YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
var date = new Date("2016-06-14");
var dateStr = date.toDateString().split(" ").slice(1,4).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/) which provide lots of date formating at easy way

```
    //convert current date to below format
    moment().format('LL');   // March 17, 2016
    moment().format('ll');   // Mar 17, 2016
```

You know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a moment.

```
//convert input date to below format
moment("2016-06-14", "YYYY-MM-DD").format('LL'); // June 14, 2016
```